# Why I'm not recovering in python variables the same counts as SQL from table

Tags: python, sql, pandas

This is my first post in Stack Overflow and I'm trying to be as concise as I can.
I have some experience in SQL but I'm just starting to code python.
I have a weird result getting SQL data in python variables and it seems I'm doing something wrong that I can't find.

My SQLite table got 26244 row as the SQL query shows:

```
table = 'DatosLaboratorio' 
SQLQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM %s" % table
rows = cursor.execute(SQLQuery).fetchone()[0]
print(rows)

26244
```

However when I try to summarize table, python is not recovering the same figures:

```
SQLQuery = "SELECT familia, COUNT(*) as num FROM %s GROUP BY familia ORDER BY familia" % table
rows = cursor.execute(SQLQuery).fetchall()
conn.commit()
# sum totals previously grouped in field 1 (num)
count=0
for row in rows:
    count=count+row[1]
print(count)

8862
```

I have verified that a direct SQL query against SQLite gives the right figures:

```
select sum(num) as total from 
(select familia, count (*) as num from DatosLaboratorio group by familia)

total 
26244
```

Worse, when I try to get data in DataFrame using pandas, I don't get the same counts, it seems pandas only reads in 33 valid rows, but I have values in all 26244 records:

```
SQLQuery = "SELECT * FROM %s" % table
df = pd.read_sql (SQLQuery,conn)
conn.commit()
df.count()

ID                     33
seccion                 0
fecha                  33
familia                33
codigo                 33
extractoseco           33
materiagrasa           33
sal                    33
ph                     33
observaciones          33
phsalmuera              0
temperaturasalmuera     4
densidadsalmuera        4
```

What am I missing? Thank you in advance for your help!

---

@Hrabal: Adding output

This is SQL output of query on SQLite:

```
select familia, count (*) as num from DatosLaboratorio group by familia

RecNo   familia num
1   CABRA BARRA TIERNO  297
2   CABRA MADURADO 3 KG 29
3   CABRA MADURADO MINI 44
4   CABRA TIERNO 3 KGS  140
5   CABRA TIERNO BARRA 4,2  50
6   CABRA TIERNO MINI   258
7   GRAN CAPITAN 3 KGS  2
8   MADURADO 3 KG SL    2588
9   MADURADO 3 KGS IQM  315
10  MADURADO 3 KGS S/LIS    308
11  MADURADO 3KG CL 1229
12  MADURADO BARRA  1585
13  MADURADO BARRA 4,2  523
14  MADURADO BARRA IQM  60
15  MADURADO BARRA IQM 4,2  41
16  MADURADO MINI   1393
...
50  TIERNO MINI IQM 142
51  TIERNO MINI LIGHT   572
52  TIERNO PÑO  323
53  TIERNO PÑO IQM  2124
54  TIERNO SOJA 3 KGS   3
55  TIERNO SOJA BARRA   14
56  TIERNO SOJA MINI    4
```

So the result is 56 rows with data grouped by "familia", and sum("num") = 26244

When I print from python, it doesn't seems to read all the data:

```
SQLQuery = "SELECT familia, COUNT(*) as num FROM %s GROUP BY familia ORDER BY familia" % table
rows = cursor.execute(SQLQuery).fetchall()
conn.commit()
columns = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]
print(columns)
for row in rows:
    print (row[0],row[1])

['familia', 'num']
CABRA BARRA TIERNO 297
CABRA MADURADO 3 KG 29
CABRA MADURADO MINI 44
CABRA TIERNO 3 KGS 140
CABRA TIERNO BARRA 4,2 50
CABRA TIERNO MINI 258
GRAN CAPITAN 3 KGS 2
MADURADO 3 KG SL 2588
MADURADO 3 KGS IQM 315
MADURADO 3 KGS S/LIS 308
MADURADO 3KG CL 1229
MADURADO BARRA 1585
MADURADO BARRA 4,2 523
MADURADO BARRA IQM 60
MADURADO BARRA IQM 4,2 41
MADURADO MINI 1393
```

That's all data python is reading in, apparently: the 16 first lines, or at least I am not able to get the rest of data in. It should be reading 56 rows.
And pandas doesn't read all the data neither.

Comment: Just a guess but do you want to use row[0] instead of row[1]?  If that's not it I would definitely start by just printing rows from python and seeing if this has something to do with handling of zeroes or missing values.

Comment: do all of those raws have primary keys? I had once encountered weird cases in sqlite where some rows had null primary keys and was giving wrong outputs.

Comment: can you post a snippet of `select familia, count (*) as num from DatosLaboratorio group by familia` ? both autputs from direct sqlite querying and trough python? tnx

Comment: @JohnE:At first I did print all the results but I didn't post them here because of space available. Now I have added more detailed output

Comment: @ustun: no primary keys defined, in fact table has no keys at all.

Comment: @Hrabal: output added to post, yw

Answer (score 1):

All I can think about is a problem in the `.fetchall()`..
Since python is giving you only the first 16 rows, fetchall() is not working so try using `.fetchone()` (if you have a small dataset) or a generator with `.fetchmany()`:

```
def ResultGenerator(cursor, arraysize=8):
  while True:
    results = cursor.fetchmany(arraysize)
    if not results:
        break
    for result in results:
        yield result

cursor = con.cursor()
SQLQuery = "SELECT familia, COUNT(*) as num FROM %s GROUP BY familia ORDER BY familia" % table
cursor.execute(SQLQuery)

for row in ResultGenerator(cursor):
    print (row[0],row[1])
```

This way python fetch only 8 rows at a time, consuming less memory (maybe it's here the problem?).

Try to play with the arraysize variable to see if something change.

resources:
[Python generators are fun](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators)

Comment: Hrabal: your code works but I still get 16 rows, no matter the size of arraysize. I have tested 8, 16, 32 and 56 and I get always the same result: 16 rows. Weird.